# Gatsby Bootstrap Dropdown Navigation doesn't toggle down

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, gatsby

I am working on my Gatsby app where I've added my code for my navigation. Basically, I've added my external bootstrap 5 alpha code on my `gatsby-ssr.js` file:

```
import React from 'react'

export const onRenderBody = ({ setPostBodyComponents }) => {
  setPostBodyComponents([
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
     integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" 
     crossorigin="anonymous" />,
      <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.3.4/aos.js"
      crossOrigin="anonymous"
      defer
    />
  ])
}
```

Then on my Layout component, I've included the CSS:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import "../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import "../assets/css/style.css"
import "../assets/css/aos.css"
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'
import Footer from '../components/Footer'
```

CSS works fine, however, the dropdown menu doesn't slide down or toggle when I click on it.

Not sure why, but does anyone knows what causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `data-target` and `id` are the same. Most of the problem are here.
Check your code.

```
<button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
 <icon>Hamburger</icon>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)? I think you are overkilling the whole process (using SSR, importing the modules, etc)

You just need to install it and import the desired components from React Bootstrap by:

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

After that, import your desired component. For example:

```js
const { Dropdown } = ReactBootstrap

const App=()=>{
   return <Dropdown>
  <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
    Dropdown Button
  </Dropdown.Toggle>

  <Dropdown.Menu>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
}


  ReactDOM.render(
   <App/>,
    document.body
  );
```

```css
.btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
[type=button]:not(:disabled), [type=reset]:not(:disabled), [type=submit]:not(:disabled), button:not(:disabled) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-toggle {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.btn-success {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #28a745;
    border-color: #28a745;
}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
[type=button], [type=reset], [type=submit], button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}
button, select {
    text-transform: none;
}
button, input {
    overflow: visible;
}
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
button {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.dropdown-toggle:after {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: .255em;
    vertical-align: .255em;
    content: "";
    border-top: .3em solid;
    border-right: .3em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: .3em solid transparent;
}

.dropdown-menu.show {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu[x-placement^=bottom], .dropdown-menu[x-placement^=left], .dropdown-menu[x-placement^=right], .dropdown-menu[x-placement^=top] {
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 10rem;
    padding: .5rem 0;
    margin: .125rem 0 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-radius: .25rem;
}

.dropdown-item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .25rem 1.5rem;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: inherit;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
}
a {
    color: #007bff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
*, :after, :before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .show>.btn-success.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1e7e34;
    border-color: #1c7430;
}
.btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
[type=button]:not(:disabled), [type=reset]:not(:disabled), [type=submit]:not(:disabled), button:not(:disabled) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-toggle {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.btn-success {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #28a745;
    border-color: #28a745;
}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
[type=button], [type=reset], [type=submit], button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}
button, select {
    text-transform: none;
}
button, input {
    overflow: visible;
}
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}

button {
    border-radius: 0;
}
.btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
button:focus:not(:focus-visible) {
    outline: 0;
}
.btn-success.focus, .btn-success:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(72,180,97,.5);
}
.btn-success.focus, .btn-success:focus, .btn-success:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #218838;
    border-color: #1e7e34;
}
.btn.focus, .btn:focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,123,255,.25);
}
[type=button]:not(:disabled), [type=reset]:not(:disabled), [type=submit]:not(:disabled), button:not(:disabled) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-toggle {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.btn-success {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #28a745;
    border-color: #28a745;
}


*, :after, :before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
  crossorigin></script>

<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"
  crossorigin></script>
  <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```